# Counting incoming edges in a directed acyclic graph

Tags: algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs

Given a directed acyclic graph (DAG), is there an algorithm that runs in **linear time** that counts the in-degree of each vertex (and the source of that edge), given that we know a root node (a node that from it you can reach every other vertex)?

Comment: What is your input? Adjacency lists? Are your nodes identified by integers 1 to n or 0 to n - 1? In that case yes, you just walk through all edges and increment a counter in an array.

Comment: Actually, my graph is the SCC graph of an original graph. The nodes are not identified by integers. They are represented as adjacency lists, and I have a topological ordering of the SCC graph

Comment: Define linear time - linear in number of edges or number of vertices, or both?

Comment: Both. $O(|V|+|E|)$ is my aim.

Comment: And I wish the downvoter would first state what is wrong with my question.

Comment: @TheNotMe Are the integers in O(|V| + |E|)?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question, @NiklasB.

Comment: @TheNotMe If the integers identifying the nodes are abitrarily large, then no, it's not possible in deterministic linear time (but it's possible in expected linear time). If they are in the range 1..n, it's possible.

Comment: Ah, then yes, they indeed are.

Comment: I would think this would depend primarily on the data structure used to store the graph - some structures would allow you to read off the incoming edges for a particular edge in `O(n)` time on the number of edges... Others would require more work, but may be more efficient for other operations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume your nodes are numbered from 1 to n. There's a simple solution: Create an array D of size n, with values initialized to 0. Then walk through all edges (v, w) and increment D[w] by one. In the end D[w] will be the in-degree of vertex w.

Comment: Great, that works, but what about "(and the source of that edge)"?

Comment: @TheNotMe Well that's not *counting* any more, but the idea is the same. Instead of an integer, let D[x] be a linked list or dynamic array. Then add v to D[w] for all edges (v,w). The size of D[x] will be the in-degree of vertex x and D[w] will be a list of all the sources

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your answer alot.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the answer to your problem:

```
public List<Integer> findIndegree(int n, List<List<Integer>> edges)
{
    List<Integer>as = new ArrayList<>();
    int[]in_deg = new int[n];
    for(int u=0;u<n;u++)
    {
        for(int x:edges.get(u))
            in_deg[x]++;
    }}
```

Here the array `in_deg` is storing the degree of the variables.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).